# How can you make explosives snowballs in 1.15.1 java edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For a map my friend was making, I was trying to make grenades but they failed.
I need a data tag that can make it so that as soon as it touches
the ground it explodes.

Answer (score -1):

You need something like this:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:snowball] at @s anchored eyes unless block ^ ^ ^1 air run summon tnt
```

obviously, this will not work for all angles but there's the template. If you don't want it to destroy blocks, summon a creeper instead:

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:snowball] at @s anchored eyes unless block ^ ^ ^1 air run summon creeper ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:0,ExplosionRadius:1}
```

and disable mob griefing **/gamerule mobGriefing false**

Comment: Interesting idea. Sadly it doesn't work, because the view direction of a snowball is completely separate from its momentum direction.